# java - overriding iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, iteration, trie

in all honesty, I've spent a few days looking at this and trying to figure it out, but have come up very short. The goal is to see if a trie node has a next, if so what it is.

Where it's called by:

```
public Iterator<String> iterator() {
    return new TrieIterator();
}
```

calls this to implement my own iterator. I've tried using a position in the array + 1 for the hasNext(), also comparing things to size, and number or nodes, and children, and have come up short. My most recent try was something along the lines of (below) but doesn't work.

```
hasNext() {
return this.children.hasChildren(); /* doesn't work */
} 

public class TrieIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    public TrieIterator(){
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return false;
    }

    public String next() {

        return null;
    }

    public void remove() {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

here's the trieNode class as well:

```
public class TrieNode {

    protected char letter = ' ';
    protected TrieNode parentNode = null;
    protected boolean fullWord = false;
    protected TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[26];
    protected int prefixes = 0;

    public TrieNode(char letter, TrieNode parentNode){
        this.letter = letter;
        this.parentNode = parentNode;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren(){
        int index = 0;

        while(index < children.length){
            if(children[index] != null) {
                return true;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public TrieNode nodeForLetter(char ch) {
        return children[ch - 97];
    }

    public boolean isEndOfWord() {
        return letter == '*';
    }
}
```

and adding and deleting is as follows:

```
public void addWord(String s) {
    if (hasWord(s)) return;

    int index = 0;
    TrieNode current = root;
    char[] letters = s.toCharArray();

    while(index < s.length()){
        TrieNode child = current.children[letters[index] - 97];
        if(child == null){
            child = new TrieNode(letters[index], current);
            child.prefixes++;
            numOfNodes++;
        }

        current = child;
        index++;

        if(index == s.length()){
            current.fullWord = true;
            numOfWords++;
        }
    }
}

public void deleteWord(String s) {
    if(s.length() == 0) return;
    if(size() == 0) return;
    if(!hasWord(s)) return;

    TrieNode current = root;
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        TrieNode child = current.children[s.charAt(ch) - 97];
        if(child.prefixes == 1){
            child = null;
            return;
        }
        else{
            child.prefixes--;
            current = child;
        }
    }
    current.fullWord = false;
}

public boolean hasWord(String s) {
    if(size() == 0) return false;

    char[] letters = s.toCharArray();
    int l = letters.length;
    TrieNode current = root;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if (current == null) return false;
        current = current.children[letters[i] - 97];
    }

    if (i == l && current == null) return false;
    if (current != null && !current.fullWord) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Please don't change current implementation of the trie :)

Comment: What "doesn't work", and how are you obtaining an instance of your iterator?

Comment: First, define how would you traverse through all the elements of your trie to do a basic task, for example, to print them. Then, implement the methods in `TrieIterator` to fulfill this behavior.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question? Are you asking for someone to write `TrieIterator` for you?

Comment: @ruakh no, i would like an explanation as to how to go about going through the trie so I can then implement the iterator myself.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's what I'm having issues with at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at implementing `hasNext()` with `this.children.hasChildren();` won't work because `children` is an array of `TrieNode`, so it doesn't have any `hasChildren()` method.

The `hasChildren()` method is a method of `TrieNode`, not its `children` array.

You need to keep track of the current node, the position in the current node, and all the characters seen so far. `hasNext()` should return true if there are any more words, which means if the node is a full word or if it has any children that haven't been visited yet that are full words. (But, I assume the leaf nodes are always full words, so the latter test can simply be if the node has any children that haven't been visited yet.)

You will need to decide if you will return shorter words before longer ones (do you return a word from `next()` as soon as you arrive at a full word node, or only after visiting its children?) You will also need to maintain a stack of nodes, so that after you have descended to a child node, you can return to your previous position in the parent node.

It isn't a trivial task. I would suggest starting with a Trie built from a very small set of words (like "a", "an", and "at"), and getting that fully debugged before you move on to three letter words or more.

(You should also consider what you intend to do if the Trie is modified while you're iterating through it. The standard `java.util` classes update a counter on every modification, and test that it hasn't changed in the iterator. If it has, they throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Iterators using this strategy are called ***fail-fast iterators***.)

Comment: And test driven development helps a lot especially when an algorithm doesn't 'fit in ones mind', cause it's easy to check that everything still works

Comment: Can you give me a hint as to how to access the current node? Then I think I have it from there! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any advice, I'm still lost 2 hours later?

Comment: The iterator would have an instance variable for the current node, which would be set to the root node initially when the iterator is created, and then would change as you iterate through the trie.